# Geometry nodes not rendering correct density in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I am trying to render cubes made with geometry nodes. In the viewport is looks OK but in the final render the amount of rendered cubes is much lower. What could be the problem?

Viewport

[image]

Render

[image]

Nodes

[image]

Comment: Do you have a subdivision modifier hooked in somewhere that is disabled in the renderer?

Comment: Hi! Yep, It was the subidivision modifier. I applied It and It worked. I don't know why is It like that, but It helped. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just to be able to mark the question as solved....*

Each modifier has two additional options:

- Realtime: Display modifier in viewport.
- Render: Use modifier during render.

[image]

Sometimes it happens that you have the modifier enabled in the viewport, but accidentally disable it in the renderer.

By activating the option *Use modifier during render* the modifier is also displayed during render.